# Very Strange Bug When Printing in Perl

Tags: perl, printing

So here's the snippet of code that's running:

```
    if($verbose){
            my $toPrint = "Added ";
            if($types[$count]){
                    $toPrint .= "$types[$count] ";
                    print "Type: $types[$count]\n"; #Manual debugging
                    print "\$toPrint: $toPrint\n"; #Manual debugging
            }
            if($addressTypes[$count]){
                    $toPrint .= "$addressTypes[$count] ";
                    print "Address Type: $addressTypes[$count]\n"; #Manual debugging
                    print "\$toPrint: $toPrint\n"; #Manual debugging
            }
            if($addresses[$count]){
                    $toPrint .= "$addresses[$count] ";
                    print "Address: $addresses[$count]\n"; #Manual Debugging
                    print "\$toPrint: $toPrint\n"; #Manual debugging
            }
            $toPrint .= "to the address entries\n";
            print "Final value of \$toPrint before printing: $toPrint\n"; #Manual debugging
            print $toPrint;
    }
```

We're inside a for loop, with `$count` being the variable we're iterating on. Here's what the output of a particular runthrough of this code looks like. For the sake of privacy, I've replaced the IP in it with ###.###.###.###.

```
    Type: zix01
    $toPrint: Added zix01
    Address Type: A
    $toPrint: Added zix01 A
    Address: ###.###.###.###
     toPrint: Added zix01 A ###.###.###.###
     to the address entries before printing: Added zix01 A ###.###.###.###

     to the address entries#.###
```

As you can see, there are several things wrong with this.

1. The line after the line starting with "Address" starts with a space instead of the intended $.
2. The line after that starts with " to the address entries" instead of "Final value of $toPrint".
3. That line also does not have " to the address entries" at the end of it.
4. There is an extra line break between the last two lines.
5. The last line does not contain the word "Added zix01 A" even though the variable it's supposed to be printing does.
6. The last line also does not include the IP it is supposed to be printing, except for the last 5 characters of it, which are coming out after the rest of the string but before the line break.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

edited for grammar.

Comment: This isn't necessarily related to your problem, but I have seen all kinds of weird print behavior caused by the print output buffer.  Try turning it off by putting this at the top of your script: $| = 1;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are there carriage return characters (`\r`) somewhere in your output? On Unix use `perl script.pl | od -c` to examine each character of output.

Files generated in Windows often have `\r\n` line endings. When those files are read in a Unix environment, `chomp` will only remove the `\n`. When I have to worry about portability, I usually skip `chomp` and just say `s/\s+$//` on the input (or `s/[\r\n]+$//` if you don't want to strip *all* the trailing whitespace).

Comment: There do appear to be carriage returns here. The script is operating on .csv files produced in Windows, which is likely where they're coming from. I used `chomp` at every sensible opportunity though so I'm not sure why they're still there. Might the carriage returns be the problem?

Comment: It does seem like the carriage returns are causing the issue. Piping into `od -c` I can see all the intended output, and there's a carriage return right before every instance the output that looks mangled without `od`. Will test your `chomp` alternative now.

Comment: You can also try running the utility `dos2unix` to remove CRLF line endings.

Comment: Replacing the initial instance of `chomp` on the input with `s/\s+$//g` and removing all other instances of `chomp` has fixed the problem. I'd vote up your answer, mob, but my account is brand new so I don't have enough reputation to do it. Side note: this also means that the script as a whole is several lines shorter now.